# Passing List Comprehension to a function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have a function in which I would like to pass list comprehension to as an input. I'm getting an error about my_list not being defined. I know I could put `my_list` outside the function, but in reality that list is generated as part of the function.

The actual definition is complex so here is simplified example:

```
def my_def(list_comp):
    global my_list
    my_list = [[1,2],[3,4]]
    list_comp_output = list_comp
    return list_comp_output

print my_def([x[1] for x in my_list])
```

Comment: `[x[1] for x in my_list]` is a list comprehension which produces a list and this list, not comprehension, is passed to the function. So your simplified function returns input list and modifies `my_list`

Comment: when calling `my_def([x[1] for x in my_list])`, python will evaluate the expression `[x[1] for x in my_list]` and pass the result to `my_def` ... `my_list` needs to be defined when calling the function ... also the result is static, so it won't change even if you change `my_list`

Comment: also, if your end goal is to create a function that applies some kind of function (like lambda x: x[1]) to all elements of a list ... it already exists, it is called mapping => see `map` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually *all we have in Python is runtime; there is no such thing as a separate compile time*<sup>1</sup>.(in the scope of interpreter). and the functions are not exception from this rule.

So what you have done here is defining `my_list` as a global variable and attempt to use it in a list comprehension, when python doesn't defined such thing.

You can just run your function 1 time then use that list comprehension :

```
def my_def(list_comp):
    global my_list
    my_list = [[1,2],[3,4]]
    list_comp_output = list_comp
    return list_comp_output


my_def([])
print my_def([x[1] for x in my_list])
[2,4]
```

Also i don't see any thing logical here :) if you want to use a global variable just define if in the scope of your module (out side the function and pass it to your function.)

```
def my_def(list_comp):
    # do stuff with list_comp
    return list_comp_output


my_list= # a costume list 
li=[x[1] for x in my_list]
print my_def(li)
```

Or more elegant do the list comprehension within your function :

```
def my_def(list_comp):
    return [x[1] for x in list_comp]
```

---

<sub>1. Learning Python by Mark Lutz</sub>

Comment: this answers the question but I'm guessing there is a better way to do what the OP wants to do (it isn't clear to me though what that is)

Comment: @JulienSpronck Yeah indeed,i was doing that ;).

Comment: @Kasra This does accomplish what I need. I don't want the list comp in the function because I am calling the function dozens of times and want to use a different list comp each time.

Comment: @user2242044 OK,but why you want to define `my_list` within function?

Comment: @kasra I think my example was just to over simplified. The function is used to hit an API and return some results. `My_List` are the results of the API query. I call that function lots of time to get various data from the API.

Comment: Except there may be separate compile time. The reference implementation first compiles the source into byte code, then it executes the bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

That's because my_list is not defined;)

First you have to realize that the body in the function definition (however if there were default arguments, these would have been evaluated right away) is not executed until the function is actually call, but the argument to it is evaluated before the function is called.

The two first statements in it says first that the symbol `my_list` is that of the global scope in this function. The second says to assign to that symbol (in global scope) the value `[[1,2],[3,4]]`. But this does as mentioned not happen before the function is called (so right after the function definition it is still not defined).

The consequence of this is that you try to evaluate `my_list` (when calling the function) before it is defined or assigned to (in the function body).

You could try to make it happen by calling `my_def([])` first, which will define `my_list`, but the correct way would probably be to put the definition of `my_list` outside the function definition:

```
my_list = [[1,2],[3,4]]

def my_def(list_comp):
   list_comp_output = list_comp
   return list_comp_output

print my_def([x[1] for x in my_list])
```

Which gives the answer:

```
[2, 4]
```

Comment: `my_def` is just an overly verbose identity function here. You pass it a list, and it returns the same list.

Comment: *"the code in the function definition is not executed until the function is actually call"* - but **more importantly** the arguments to the function are evaluated before the function is called.